# Math in GNU Parallel

Tags: bash, perl, gnu-parallel

The one thing I'm trying to do, is have a little bit of math done with the {%} option in [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

```
cat short | parallel -j 2 echo my_prog ----in {} ----out {/.}.extension ----gpu {= {%}+1 =} {= {%}-1 =}
```

(I have extra dashes in front of `in`, `out` and `gpu` just in case.)

The math shown within `{= =}` is all I need to do, and I'm just not sure I understand how to write it with `--rpl` and `--parens`

`{=   =}` is the space where one can write a Perl expression in GNU parallel.

Also my program isn't running here, I'm just echoing the output to see if everything will be correct.

Could someone please explain how to do this simple math within the command?

My error is this:

```
parallel: Error: Cannot use {%}+1 : Missing right curly or square bracket at (eval 13) line 2, at end of line
syntax error at (eval 13) line 2, at EOF
```

Comment: Sorry, can't understand what you're trying to do. Parallelising code means you run two (isolated) processes in parallel. You need to capture and collate and results.

Comment: This is using gnu parallels, assume that my_prog is the program that will be running in parallel. I have echo in front just to make sure that all my arguments for my_prog are correct. Currently in this example, gnu parallels will run echo in parallel.

Comment: What is in `short`? What is the result that you get from this command? Why do you think it's wrong? It seems very odd to do arithmetic on the parallel job number `{%}`

Comment: short just contains a list of directories. Those will just be used in those in and out sections. Error has been added.

Comment: I'm assuming theres a conflict with using {= =} and {%} within those sections.

Comment: It is probably better to use `--dry_run` than to add `echo` as the ccommand

Comment: --rpl 'tag perl expression'
                Use tag as a replacement string for perl expression. This makes it possible to define your own
                replacement strings. GNU parallel's 7 replacement strings are implemented as:
                  --rpl '{%} 1 $_=$job->slot()'

Comment: This is listed in the manual

Comment: --rpl '{%} 1 $_=$job->slot()'

Comment: I'm just not 100% sure how to use this section, (I do not know perl).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Problem #1

You need to escape the Perl program so it doesn't get processed by the shell. Using single quotes around the program is the usual method used.

### Problem #2

Looks like `{%}` is not replaced within `{= =}`, which makes sense. `{= =}` says "*you have full access to all of GNU parallel's internal functions and data structures*", so it becomes a question of finding the var/fun that provides the slot number.

### Problem #3

It's the value of `$_` that's inserted into the command, so you need to assign the sum to `$_`.

### Solution

```
{= '$_ = $job->slot() + 1' =}
```

Comment: Shall test and get back to you.

Comment: Works. Thank you very much :)